# Apache2 service won't start in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-15.10

I have installed apache2 but it's won't start, when i do

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

it's give me this problem

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with    error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

so when i enter this command

```
 systemctl status apache2.service
```

it's give me this message

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since ن 2016-04-11 15:41:07 WEST; min  43s ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 19644 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=2)

11 15:41:07 oussama-UL50VT systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
11 15:41:07 oussama-UL50VT apache2[19644]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 64: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
11 15:41:07 oussama-UL50VT apache2[19644]: /etc/init.d/apache2: 76: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
11 15:41:07 oussama-UL50VT systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
11 15:41:07 oussama-UL50VT systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
11 15:41:07 oussama-UL50VT systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
11 15:41:07 oussama-UL50VT systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
11 15:41:07 oussama-UL50VT apache2[19644]: ERROR: APACHE_PID_FILE needs to be defined in /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Comment: If you have relevant log entries, or information about the Apache configuration, it might help us diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your apache installation has broken... Please try reinstalling apache by running the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Answer (score 2):

run this command.

- apachectl start

the output should show exactly what is missing in the mods load folder.
Install the indicated missing mod run command again install missing mods untill apache starts.

This worked for me on linux mint 18